# Return an array of books of authors, many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I have two models, Author and Book and a middle table middleItem. There is a many to many relationship. My task is to create a variable @myBooks that returns an array of all Books that the author has. However, we will search by the author id in the session session[:user_id]

```
class middleItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :book
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :middleItem
  has_many :author, through: :middleItem
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :middleItem
  has_many :books, through: :middleItem
end
```

However it doesn't work

```
Book.joins(:authors).joins(:middleItem).where(middleItem: {user_id: session[:user_id]}).distinct.map {|x| puts x.name}
```

**Edit:**
Authors: (1)Shakespeare, (2)Orwell
Books: (1) Romeo and Juliet, (2) Hamlet, (3) Animal Farm

Middle table: (1,1), (1,2), (2,3)

@myBooks should be:" romeo and juliet, hamlet" if let's say session[:user_id] is 1

Comment: well besides the query that need some work I think you have a typo within your book model it should say :authors

Comment: Not sure I understand some parts for this but based purely on your code `Book.joins(:authors).where(authors: {id: session[:user_id]})` should suffice. Sidenote: `map {|x| x.any_db_attribute_here}` can always be shortened to `pluck(:any_db_attribute_here)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to make things clearer, check the edit

Comment: @engineersmnky This works perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think a good fit for this problem is to use `scopes`, you can define the scope within your `book` model as below:

```rb
scope :search_by_author, ->(author_id) { joins(:authors).where(Author.arel_table[:id].eq(author_id)).distinct}
```

The above can be used like: `Book.search_by_author(1)` and if you really need an array instead of an ActiveRecord result you can cast the result to an array: `Book.search_by_author(1).to_a`.

Hope the above helps!

Comment: A few constructive comments: 1) You can use `Author.arel_attribute(:id)` instead of `Author.arel_table[:id]`; 2) for simple use cases like equality `where(table_name: { column_name: value})` is generally considered more idiomatic than using `Arel`; 3) `+ []` is an awkward way of converting an `ActiveRecord::Relation` to an `Array` instead use [`to_a`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-to_a) .

Comment: Thx for the comments @ngineersmnky, will edit my answer so is more useful/clear, although I do prefer to keep the arel_table approach thx 